# Inverse laplace transform for $ \frac{s^2+1}{s^2(s+1)}$

Tags: laplace-transform, laplace-method

I used partial fractions so I equated the numerator $s^2+1=A(s+1) +Bs^2$ and I found $A$ and $B$ constants to be $A=1$ and $B=2$. When I inverse it I got the answer: $t +2\exp(-t)$ but the answer is $t + 2\exp(-t) -1$?
From partial fractions I can only get two terms how did the inverse laplace $-1$ come about?

Answer (score 1):

***Hint***

You need three fractions

$$ \frac{s^2+1}{s^2(s+1)}= \frac A s + \frac B {s^2}+\frac C  {s+1}$$

$$
\begin{cases}
B=1 \\
A+C=1\\
A+B=0
\end{cases}
$$

Then,
$$y(t)=A+Bt+Ce^{-t}$$